# Kubuntu 20.04: non-english filename characters show as question marks on usb sticks mounted through the terminal

Tags: usb, permissions, mount, kubuntu, locale

... but show correctly if the usb stick is mounted through dolphin.

The usb stick is formatted in `fat32` and has personal data files copied from a `windows7` system.

**Is there a way to show the filenames correctly when mounted from the terminal and with file ownership from the local user?**

The characters in question i tried, are Greek and German (with umlaut), and the filenames look something like this `??? ?????? ???.txt` for example.

If I copy and paste these files from the usb stick to the hard drive, or navigate to the files from the terminal,  nothing changes.

I have installed Greek and German locales in many variants, language packs, additional fonts ...

```
fo@dawn:~$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
de_DE
de_DE.iso88591
de_DE.utf8
deutsch
el_CY
el_CY.iso88597
el_CY.utf8
el_GR
el_GR@euro
el_GR.iso88597
el_GR.iso88597@euro
el_GR.utf8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IL
en_IL.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
german
greek
POSIX
fo@dawn:~$
```

Have run `locale-gen`, `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, changed `LC_ALL=` to German and Greek, so that the whole of Kubuntu was in German or Greek.

Also through the terminal, only `root` can mount a drive and of course all files are then owned by `root`, and I suppose because of the `fat32` format, `chown` does not work.

On the other hand, dolphin mounts the usb stick with all files owned by the local user!

Answer (score 0):

Since I posted this question I did more research and came up with the following:

Create a mount point with `mkdir /media/user/mount-point-name`, 
change ownership from root to user with `chown user:user mount-point-name`, and give rw permissions with `chmod 644 mount-point-name`.

Create an fstab entry:
edit fstab with `sudo nano /etc/fstab`
add the following line: `LABEL=drive-label-name   /media/user/mount-point-name   vfat   user,utf8,noauto  0  2`

Now, a breakdown of the fstab entry:
`LABEL=` works just like `UUID=`, so now you can mount the usb stick by issuing `mount LABEL=drive-label-name`, 
the second part is the path to the mount point, 
`vfat` is for fat format type and afterwards come 
the mount options: 
`user` is the option that lets us mount as normal user, 
`utf8` has made all fonts display correctly, 
`noauto` so that it is not mounted automatically, 
the `0` is the dump, and 
`2` means the drive should be checked with `fsck` after `1`, meaning after / and /boot/efi partitions.

Hope this helps somebody!